# Cannot print to network (lpd) printer

Tags: networking, printing

The same physical device as in [the other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/694819/80483), but connected to using `lpd`. 
I created it using the `Add` dialogue:

- Device URI: `lpd://Sales/BINARY_P1`
- Printer State: `Processing - Unable to locate printer "Sales".`

Printing test page results in the printer queue listing it with status `Processing - Not connected?`.

As per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems, here is the information:

### ping

`ping 192.168.X.P` succeeds (the IP is written on the printer)

### nmap

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.X.P
Host is up (0.00062s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
23/tcp   open  telnet
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp
9100/tcp open  jetdirect
MAC Address: 30:05:5C:2B:2E:46 (Brother industries)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 35.28 seconds`
```

### snmp

`network lpd://Sales/BINARY_P1 "Brother MFC-8950DW" "Brother MFC-8950DW" "MFG:Brother;CMD:PJL,PCL,PCLXL,URF;MDL:MFC-8950DW;CLS:PRINTER;CID:Brother Laser Type2;URF:W8,CP1,IS11-19-4,MT1-3-4-5-8-11,OB10,PQ4,RS300-600-1200,DM1;" ""`

### dnssd

`network dnssd://Sales%20Brother%20Printer._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c2b2e46 "Brother MFC-8950DW" "Sales Brother Printer" "MFG:Brother;MDL:MFC-8950DW;CMD:PJL,PCL,PCLXL,URF;" ""`

### lpinfo

network lpd://Sales/BINARY_P1

### avahi-browse

```
+  wlan0 IPv6 Sales Brother Printer                         Internet Printer     local
+  wlan0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         Internet Printer     local
+   eth0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         Internet Printer     local
+  wlan0 IPv6 Sales Brother Printer                         _ipps._tcp           local
+  wlan0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         _ipps._tcp           local
+   eth0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         _ipps._tcp           local
+   eth0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         PDL Printer          local
+   eth0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         Web Site             local
+   eth0 IPv4 Sales Brother Printer                         _ipp-tls._tcp        local
=  wlan0 IPv6 Sales Brother Printer                         UNIX Printer         local
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
aa-complain cupsd
mkdir /usr/share/cups/model
mkdir /var/spool/lpd
apt-get update
apt-get install sane-utils gimp
```

Close a terminal.

Download these files

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101123/brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101125/brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb

Turn on the printer and connect the network cable.

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
cd /home/user/Downloads    
dpkg -i --force-all  brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all  brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb   
nano /etc/printcap.local
```

Replace ":lp" line to the following 2 lines

```
:rm=(ip address of your printer)\
:rp=lp\
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano.

Download these files

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006646/brscan4-0.4.3-2.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006651/brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb

Turn on your MFC/DCP and connect the USB cable.

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
cd /home/user/Downloads    
dpkg -i --force-all  brscan4-0.4.3-2.i386.deb
dpkg -i  --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb
dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
brscan-skey
brscan-skey -l
```

Check if the scan-key-tool detect your scanner device.

Press the scan button, select user, select destination, press START.

Close a terminal.

Download these files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006656/brmfcfaxlpd-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006658/brmfcfaxcups-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006665/brfaxmodem-1.1.3-1.i386.deb

Turn on the MFC/FAX and connect the cable.

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
cd /home/user/Downloads  
dpkg -i --force-all brmfcfaxlpd-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all brmfcfaxcups-1.0.0-1.i386.deb
dpkg -i brfaxmodem-1.1.3-1.i386.deb
```

Comment: this is far too confusing. what is Ctrl-Alt-T? what are these packages I am supposed to install? Why do I need them?

Comment: Go to: http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on

Comment: lol -- `Ctrl+Alt+T` just opens a new terminal window.